# Bootstrap tooltip/popover stops work after reload specific div using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application in ASP.NET MVC 5, in which one the screens are a CRUD made via Ajax. There is also a table to show the infos with buttons to manage them. After I do a action I update the table using the following command: **$('# tbName').load(location.href + '#tbName');** but the tooltips in buttons stop work after the command like you can see in the bellow GIF:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwO26.gif 
**Button code:**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar registro"                                             onclick="getSalario('@salario.Id');">
  <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
</a>
```

**Javascript Ajax code:**

```
     $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("AtualizaSalarioPessoaFisica")',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: JSON.stringify({ salarioPessoaFisica: salario }),
      success: function (data) {
         $('#modalEditarSalario').modal('hide');
         $('#tbSalario').load(location.href + ' #tbSalario');
      }
    });
```

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Normally when the page loads, bootstrap.js automatically initialises the tooltip for elements with `data-toggle="tooltip"` attribute. but when you reloads the content it won't initialises the tooltip. So you have to manually initialise it after `.load()` method like this `$('#example').tooltip(options)` for more info http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: I tried to use this code:  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); for inicialize the tooltip again but it doesn't worked!

Comment: You have to put it inside ajax success method after load method

Comment: I know, I did it, but doesn't worked!

Answer (score 2):

I achived solve my problem inicializing the tooltip in a callback function after reload the div. I used the following code:

```
$('#tbSalario').load(location.href + ' #tbSalario', function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```